# When is it useful to have broadcast data in deserialized form?

Tags: serialization, apache-spark

Reading the docs for Spark I see

> The data broadcasted this way is cached in serialized form and deserialized before running each task. This means that explicitly creating broadcast variables is only useful when tasks across multiple stages need the same data or **when caching the data in deserialized form is important**.

I understand why broadcasts variables are useful when re-using them in multiple tasks.  You don't want to re-send them with all closures.

However the second part, in bold, says when caching data in deserialized form is important.  When and why would that be important?  If you're only going to use data in 1 task it will still get serialized/deserialized once, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ignored following part:

> and deserialized before running **each task**.

A single stage typically consist of multiple tasks (it is not common to have only a single partition, is it?) and multiple tasks belonging to the same stage can be processed by the same executor. Since deserialization can be quite expensive you may prefer to perform it only once.